# After redirected, meta-refresh from old Page still excecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, meta-tags

I have a strange Problem i can't handle at the moment. I have tried a lot of things and nothing helps.

I have a simple page with a form containing 4 hidden inputs. These inputs are filled in with jQuery. After that's done, i submit the Form using jQuery.

For the possibility that a user doesn't have Javascript, i included a `metaRefresh` Tag in my Page-Load Event at the time of the First Request.

It works as expected when a User doesn't have JavaScript. But when it is activated, even if the Redirect is executed , after these defined 10 seconds, the meta tag will execute, even if i arrived on the next Page.

I am really frustrated at the Moment, its a complete nonsense for me, i don't understand how this could be. Are there some special circumstances causing such a special Behavior?

Maybe there is also an alternate Option to force a Page Change when JS is deactivated.

**Addition:**

Code to add Refresh-Tag:

```
var refreshTag = new HtmlGenericControl("meta");
refreshTag.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "refresh");
refreshTag.Attributes.Add("content", "10; URL=" + Request.RawUrl + "&rp=3");
head.Controls.Add(refreshTag);
```

Code for Refresh:

in all Cases the Refresh Tag will be excecuted.

```
Response.Redirect(link, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
return;
```

OR

```
Response Redirect(link,true);
```

OR

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";                
Response.AddHeader("Location", link);
```

Comment: Can you share the actual code where you include the metaRefresh tag, and also the redirection code.

Comment: Do you have try to detect [browser capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3yekbd5b(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: No i did not because i thought that this helps not to solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the redirect behavior you should avoid including the meta-tag into your master page, because it will be rendered on every page even after redirects.

An alternative option could be to wrap you meta-tag in a `noscript` element that will execute the meta refresh only if Javascript is deactivated:

```
 var noscriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("noscript");

 var refreshTag = new HtmlGenericControl("meta");
 refreshTag.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "refresh");
 refreshTag.Attributes.Add("content", "10; URL=" + Request.RawUrl + "?rp=3");

 noscriptTag.Controls.Add(refreshTag);

 this.Header.Controls.Add(noscriptTag);
```

The rendered output in the `Head` element would look like:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=/?rp=3"></meta>
</noscript>
```

For more info on the noscript tag, check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

This will prevent the meta-tag behavior when JS is activated.

Comment: So simple and effective. Thank you very much. That was a really great Solution and works like a charm.